# Javascript - Onblur refocus

Tags: prototype

I have compiled two codes from this page for text fields and dropdowns menus. The code is working except that after going to another field it jumps back and forth non-stop. I'm guessing that my problem must be in the loop somewhere but can't find it. Thanks in advance! [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/kKkF2/)

```
function doThisOnBlur() {   
      if (this.value==='') {   var ths = $(this);  setTimeout(function(){
         ths.focus();
        }, 1);  return false; }

}

var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
var selects = document.getElementsByTagName('select');

for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++)
{ inputs[i].onblur = doThisOnBlur; }
for (i = 0; i < selects.length; i++)
{  selects[i].onblur = doThisOnBlur; }
```

Comment: It is doing what you told it to.  If I don't enter a value in the first field, and click on the second field, the first field executes the function, doThisOnBlur, then the second field loses focus and executes the function, doThisOnBlur.  They get caught in a loop since both are constantly losing focus to one another.

Comment: CM thanks, I see.. How do I do to make it to stay in the first field that it's still empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I made a change that I think will work based on your jsfiddle.  I set a global variable to hold null or the current active field.  Once the active field gets a value, then the variable is set back to null, and the user can proceed to the next field.

```
var hasPrecedence = null;

function doThisOnBlur() {
  if(!hasPrecedence){ hasPrecedence = this; }
  if(hasPrecedence != this){ return; }
  if (this.value==='') {   var ths = $(this);  setTimeout(function(){ 
     ths.focus();
  }, 1);  return false; }
  else{
    hasPrecedence = null;
  }
}
```

​

Comment: @Skorpion, I'm glad that I could help.